# How to specify which handler to route Mediator query/command?

Tags: cqrs, mediatr

I am exploring how to condense how I was taught the MediatR package's awesome infrastructure.  I feel like this class:

```
    public class GetExamplesQuery : IRequest<GetExamplesResponse>
    {
        public GetExamplesQuery() { }
    }
```

Should be able to drive something like...

```
public class GetAllExamples : GetExamplesResponse { }
```

and then maybe without much trouble...

```
public class GetExamplesByIds : GetExamplesResponse { }
```

So... does that work?

Can you recommend a better pattern?  It seems like a `.Service` layer should interpret the needs of `.Api`, and link it with the resources of `.Data` without every query having it's own trio of Query/Handler/Response classes.  That's a hard sell to the department that's been free-balling for years.

Also, bless you if you just point me to an existing resource!  Maybe I just want to blab about 2024 best practices.